# Symfony console single command with no arguments

Tags: php, symfony, console-application

I'm trying to build a simple command-line application with the Symfony 2 console component: it should have only one command available, and not require any argument, but it should accept options, as this:

```
$ my-command
$ my-command --config="config/path.json"
$ my-command --test
$ my-command --config="config/path.json" --test
```

I'm following [this guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/single_command_tool.html) to make a single-command application. The Application class extension is basically the same as the guide, the customized command is something like this:

```
use \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class MyCommand extends Command
{
    public function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('my-command')
                ->setDescription('My Command')
                ->addOption('config', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Config path')
                ->addOption('test', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Is Test?');
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('Nevermind...');
    }
}
```

However, these are the results in each of the previous cases (except the first, without options, which works right):

```
$ my-command --test
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
       php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] -- [args...]
       php [options] -a

  -a               Run as interactive shell
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -r <code>        Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?>
  -B <begin_code>  Run PHP <begin_code> before processing input lines
  -R <code>        Run PHP <code> for every input line
  -F <file>        Parse and execute <file> for every input line
  -E <end_code>    Run PHP <end_code> after processing all input lines
  -H               Hide any passed arguments from external tools.
  -s               Output HTML syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Output source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.

  args...          Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument
               starts with - or script is read from stdin

  --ini            Show configuration file names

  --rf <name>      Show information about function <name>.
  --rc <name>      Show information about class <name>.
  --re <name>      Show information about extension <name>.
  --ri <name>      Show configuration for extension <name>.
```

The only way to make it work, seemingly, is defining at least one argument, and calling the command passing that one argument to it (as in`$ my-command some-argument --test`). I couldn't manage to make this command work calling it with only options.

Any idea how to make it work?

Thank you all.

Comment: are you trying to call the command name directly with php? maybe try calling the script which holds the command, passing the command name as argument

Comment: php app/console in a sf2 standard installation...

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer, but it was really a silly thing..i was so concerned with how Symfony console works that i didn't see that the problem was in the way i called the command: i was using a bash script with a line like `php -f bootstrap.php $@`, where `bootstrap.php` is the name of the main php script, the one where the Symfony Application is built. After erasing the `-f` option everything worked like a charm.. As soon as i can answer the question i will, so to "close" it.

Comment: For those who came here because they searched for a way to create single-command using console symfony component (the component, not the framework though), that's here > http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/single_command_tool.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comment above, the problem wasn't due to Symfony console.